# Проблема с mongoose (работа с двумя таблицами)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

У меня есть 2 таблицы:

```
users = {
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  } //,
  //+ стандартное поле _id
}
```

и

```
comments = {
  idUser: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
  },
  commentText: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  } //,
  //+ стандартное поле _id
}
```

Нужно на выходе получить массив типа:

```
[{
  _id: 813215615,
  commentText: "qweqweqweqw",
  username: "oleg"
}, {
  _id: 313545645,
  commentText: "dfsddfsdfsdf",
  username: "max"
}]
```

И вот с этим начинаются проблемы.
Как это сделать, при том что запросы `find()` и `findById()` асинхронные?
Вот как я это пытался сделать:

```
async.waterfall([
  function(callback) {
    Comment.find({}, callback)
  },
  function(comments, callback) {
    var i = 0;
    comments_ = [];
    comments.map(function(comment) {
      comments_[i++] = comment;
      User.findById(comment.idUser, function(err, user) {
        comments_[i].username = user.username //здесь перестает видеть массив comments_
      });
    });
    callback(null, comments_)
  }
], function(err, result) {
  log.info(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант (не проверял):

```
async.waterfall([
  function(callback) {
    Comment.find({}, callback)
  },
  function(comments, callback) {
    async.each(comments, function(comment, cb){
      User.findById(comment.idUser, function(err, user) {
        if(err) return cb(err);
        comment.username = user.username;
        cb();
      });
    }, function(err){
       callback(err, comments);
    });
  }
], function(err, result) {
  log.info(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

А вообще вам лучше посмотреть на [Mongoose.Population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все решилось одной строкой:
Comment.find({}).populate('idUser', 'username').exec(function (err, comments) {
 if (err) return HttpError(err);



 log.info(JSON.stringify(comments) + "+++++++++++++++");
})